# PHP transaction will not complete

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

My PHP transaction will not execute. I can access it though, because the "insert into" works properly. But when I insert into "paid", I want to delete the players data from "tickets_given" - but that doesn't work.

Can you see some mistakes in my code?

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    $playerId = $_POST['playerId'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $ticket->registerPayment($playerId, $amount);
}

<form action='?registerPayment=<?php echo $playerId; ?>' method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="playerId" value="<?php echo $playerId; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="register" value="true">
            <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" required="required" placeholder="Beløb"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Registrér betaling" name="payment_submit"/><br />
</form>

function registerPayment($playerId, $amount) {
        $this->conn->beginTransaction();
        $query = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO paid (ref_player, amount) VALUES ('$playerId', '$amount')");          
        $query->execute();
        $query = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM tickets_given WHERE ref_player = '$playerId'");
        $this->conn->commit();
        return $query;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't `execute` your `DELETE` query.

Comment: @O.Jones Oh yeah, what a brainfart!!!!

Comment: We've all been there, bro.